# Retrieving Inherited Attributes from Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've defined a parent `styleable` for some custom views as follows

```
<declare-styleable name="ParentView">
    <attr name="color" format="color" />
    <attr name="rotate" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I've then defined a child `styleable` that inherits the attributes from the parent styleable, i.e.,

```
<declare-styleable name="ParentView.ChildView">
    <attr name="state">
        <enum name="state0" value="0"/>
        <enum name="state1" value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Now, I can retrieve the attribute values from the child styleable in my custom view, but not any attributes from its parent styleable, i.e., setting my custom view in xml as

```
<com.example.android.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:color="@color/orange"
    custom:state="state1" />
```

and using the following code in my custom view's constructor

```
TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ParentView_ChildView, 0, 0);
    try {
        state = array.getInt(R.styleable.ParentView_ChildView_state, state);
        color = array.getInt(R.styleable.ParentView_color, Color.WHITE);
    }
    finally {
        array.recycle();
    }
```

I retrieve the `state` attribute correctly, but the `color` attribute always just gives its default value, i.e. white. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined color as a format of color in your attr file, yet you are doing getInt in your code.

Try changing this line

```
color = array.getInt(R.styleable.ParentView_color, Color.WHITE);
```

to

```
color = array.getColor(R.styleable.ParentView_color, Color.WHITE);
```