# Inherit onClick attribute from Buttom

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I am building a custom view from a `Button`, and I want to inherit the `onClick` attribute on XML. I checked the `View` source code and tried to copy it, but it uses private class [`AppCompatViewInflater.DeclaredOnClickListener`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater.java#422).

```java
    case R.styleable.View_onClick:
        if (context.isRestricted()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
                    + "be used within a restricted context");
        }

        final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
        if (handlerName != null) {
            setOnClickListener(new DeclaredOnClickListener(this, handlerName));
        }
        break;
```

I feel like there should be an easier way of doing this without going down this rabbit hole.

I am currently getting this error:

```xml
    <com.domain.SomeButton
        <!---Other stuff-->
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.doSomething()}" />
```

```
Cannot assign callback expression to 'android:onClick'

Make sure you aren't using lambda syntax if the expression should only return a value directly
```

There are related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912425/retrieving-inherited-attributes-from-custom-view) but they are unanswered and old.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit", exactly? If you mean to duplicate the exact same behavior, for whatever reason, you can just copy out that `OnClickListener` implementation, though I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. All it does is use reflection to attempt to find the method and execute it. Or just create your own `OnClickListener` from that attribute value however you mean to use it.

Comment: Hey Mike. I explained in the post I cannot copy the impl because those classes are not public. I want to replace the 'Button' with my custom view in the XML and keep it working without any more changes. Ideally, I would like to make use of the base `View` impl (that's what I mean by 'inherit'), it should be easier to maintain.

Comment: "I explained in the post I cannot copy the impl because those classes are not public." – Huh? How does that affect the right-click copy/paste options in your browser/editor? "I want to replace the 'Button'...and keep it working without any more changes." – You can already do that without touching that attribute at all, since the `View` class will set the platform-equivalent handler for the `android:onClick` attribute. Your overall question is rather unclear, but if you think that attribute is specific to the `Button` class, it's not. It works on any `View`, even without the appcompat inflater.

Comment: Hi Mike. Sorry I didn't express myself clearly. Of course I can copy paste, but I don't want to do that when there's a mechanism already in place that is maintaned by Google. _You can already do that without touching that attribute at all_, I can't, I updated the post with my XML and error. I would expect any `View` to take `onClick` but it doesn't work so my assumption was that attributes were not inherited by subtypes.

Comment: I know it's possibly a little confusing, but that's a completely different thing. That's data binding, and its framework will be processing that `onClick` attribute at build time, not a `LayoutInflater` at runtime, neither the platform class, nor the appcompat factory you've linked to. I never did do much with data binding, so I'm not sure what's wrong specifically, but this should give you a little better lead for searching. I might have a look into it later on, if I get a chance.

Comment: Hey Mike. I understand what you are saying, but have no idea about it. Can it be modified somehow or is it built into Android Studio/Jetpack ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you or somebody on your team had to set it up, 'cause it's not automatically added to a project. It is a library, but that will be pretty transparent after the initial setup, as it does all of its work quietly at build time. Despite my inexperience with it, I would have to think that your initial approach of somehow inheriting this is not correct. Data binding doesn't really care what type your `View` is. There's likely just some oversight in the syntax there, or in the `ViewModel`/method, or something. The `onClick` attribute itself isn't what you should be looking at, is what I mean.

Comment: I meant I know how to set it up, but no idea how it works under the hood. Where did you check what does Data Binding care about ? All I did was replace `Button` with my custom one. It was working before, so, if what you say is true, it should work now, but it doesn't. Could you elaborate more on this or share what you read ?

Comment: Firstly, I'm not saying that the error is definitely coming from the data binding framework. I'm saying that the XML you've provided is not being handled by the classic `onClick`-to-`OnClickListener` mechanism that you show in the question. Secondly, inheritance makes no sense in this context, for various reasons. Beyond that, everything else is speculation, especially since we have no idea what the whole, actual setup is, or where or how you're being presented with this error, which you're the only one who has ever had apparently, at least according to Google.

Comment: I want to add a feature to all buttons in the app, why doesn't inheritance fit here ? I looked at the build again and I noticed another data binding problem, which might be causing this: `Kotlin plugin is applied to the project :app but we cannot find the KaptTask. Make sure you apply the kotlin-kapt plugin because it is necessary to use kotlin with data binding.`. I have done some cleanup but it's still not gone. I am hoping that will do it. Any comments/ideas are welcome.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808379/android-data-binding-how-to-avoid-cannot-find-the-kapttask-warning) post could be related but I asked for clarifications.

Comment: XML attributes are not Java class code. You can't inherit them. Also, the appcompat inflater helper you linked is completely external to any `View`, so you cannot inherit that, either. If anything, you've already "inherited" all of that just by being a descendant of the `View` class. That's why it didn't make sense.

Comment: It turns out it was some confusion because the `Button` implemented an `OnClickListener` which contains method `onClick`. It also _overrode (?)_ some methods like `setOnClickListener` but I am not sure that mattered. I will post an answer soon. Thanks for all the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, `android:onClick` is not tied to `Button` or a specific `View`. Any `View` has it by default. My problem was it was clashing with something else.

This was my `Button` implementation:

```kotlin
class SomeButton() : Button, View.OnClickListener {

    // Constructors ignored

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        // Code
    }
}
```

This `override fun onClick` was interfiering with the `android:onClick` XML attribute. Removing it solves the problem, but using `android:onClickListener` also works.